# Literals: Do they take up memory?

Tags: c++, memory, literals

### a:

```
4;
4.0f;
"text";
```

### b:

```
4.0/5.3;
1.0f*2.3f+3.5f;
"super" + "man";
```

**Questions**

1) Does this code take up memory?

2) Does the code in b take up more memory than the code in a?

3) Could anyone explain in detail what happens internally?

EDIT:
"super" + "man" is a bad example, it's not correct in the first place. (thanks to Michael Krelin)
Secondly, putting strings in the example was a bad idea.

Comment: The code in (a) will occupy the space required for 1 int + 1 float + a 5 char string. The code in (b) will require the space for 2 floats + 9 char string.

Comment: The code you posted here, if taken literally, is dead code and will be removed by every compiler that even *tries* to optimize.

Comment: @MarcB did you mean that the code in (b) will require the space for 1 double, 1 float, and an array of 9 chars("superman\0")?

Comment: @xcrypt: depends on what the 4.0/5.3 evaluates to. Would that always be a double?

Comment: @MarcB I don't have enough experience to claim that. But I think it does always evaluate to a double. EDIT: const double to be exact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the compiler, the computer's architecture, etc.

The compiler will most likely calculate the values of these expressions at compile time if it can be sure that the result is always the same. The result of the expression can then be placed directly into the output file, instead of the instructions needed to calculate the result. But as far as I am aware the compiler is not required to perform these sorts of optimizations.

If the expression is evaluated at compile time, the performance at runtime will be the same as  if you wrote the result directly in the source code.

Comment: Provided that all terms are constant and known at compile time.

Comment: what about multiplying a non-literal integer datamember with a int literal? Does the int literal take up 4 bytes in this case?

Comment: @xcrypt: It is up to the completely up to compiler to choose. It depends on the specific compiler, computer architecture, optimization settings, context, etc. If you write `a * 2` it could store 2 in a 32-bit register then call the multiply instruction. Or it could use a bitshift. Or it could do "add ax, ax". The best is to compile the code and look at the binary in a disassembler and see what is going on in your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Does this code take up memory?

Yes

> 2) Does the code in b take up more memory than the code in a?

Depends on the machine code resulting from the compiler. Probably it does.

> 3) Could anyone explain in detail what happens internally?

Read about the [code segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) and the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

Comment: I'm not in the downvoting mood, but 2nd answer is generally wrong. Maybe universally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

All numeric expressions are evaluated at compile time as Mark said above. The numeric literals then become [immediate arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Immediate.2Fliteral). However, to the other part of your question, the string literals do take up memory. Usually they're stored in a read-only section of the memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not the code, but if it's used in the code, it should be placed *somewhere*.
2. No, it's evaluated at compile time, except for `"super" + "man"` which is simply wrong, it should be `"super" "man"` to be concatenated at compile time. And "superman" is bigger than "text". As well as "4" (integer) may take less than "4.0/5.3" (float).
3. Internally compiler evaluates constant expressions and puts them *somewhere*. The rest depends on what do you refer to as "memory". It is somewhere in your program's address space.